# FILE_EXISTS_RENAME in "file_save_data" sometime doesn't rename the existing file name and throws error for duplicate entry in "file_managed" entry

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a lot of different images with the same name having different paths. I'm uploading them using file_save_data function using FILE_EXISTS_RENAME for renaming existing image with the same name.
I'm processing file through CRON, first time renaming of file works perfect but when I process again then renaming doesn't continue after the last renaming number that is attached at the end of the file. It throws an error like "file name with key 'example_1.jpg' already exists for field 'URI' ".

Can you please help me out with the issue like what is the problem actually.

Comment: you can try to use filefield_paths module to handle it https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths

Comment: @Fky Thanks for the reply but it's not resolving my renaming problem. I am writing to fetch image from external URL and attach it to the node.

Comment: ok, check this post https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13340/how-to-programmatically-add-image-from-external-url-using-media-module

Answer (score 1):

With the FILE_EXISTS_RENAME option the filename is made unique by incrementing a counter but the uri in the file record is kept the same. However, in the file_manged table the 'uri' field is a key.